# Solving a Probabilistic Integral Equation

Tags: integration, statistics, systems-of-equations, exponential-distribution

The following problem arose for an example that I wanted to give in my paper:

Prove (or disprove) that there exists a function $g\colon {\mathbb R_+} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R_+} g(y) x \mathrm{e}^{-yx} \mathrm{d} y = x^2 \text{.} $$
If it exists, state what $g$ is.

As for the motivation for this problem: For example, if the question was finding $g\colon {\mathbb R_+} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that
$$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R_+} g(y) x \mathrm{e}^{-yx} \mathrm{d} y = \frac1{x^2} $$
The answer would easily be $g(y) = \frac12 y^2 $

Even if this can't be solved, is there a reference that might be useful for solving such problems?

Comment: an probabilistic --> a probabilistic

Comment: What is ${\cal Y}$?

Comment: If $ \mathcal{Y} $ is $ \mathbb{R}_+ $, you want the Laplace transform of $g$ equal to $ x\mapsto x $ since there is an $x$ in the LHS. Differentiating in $x$ both sides gives you the Laplace transform of $ h : y \mapsto y g(y) $ equal to 1. This implies that $h$ is the Dirac mass, hence $g$ is 0. Thus, such a function does not exist. If $ \mathcal{Y} $ is not $ \mathbb{R}_+ $ but is included in it, you can still include it in $g$ with an indicator.

Comment: ${\cal Y}= \mathbb{R}_+ $ Thank you very much for the answer.